# How can I get the Object from a Field/Class using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using reflection to get the Field at another Class, but when I try to use the `f.set(...)` to set a value into the Field, I dont have a Object, only the Class.

I code something similar to this:

```
Class<?> c = null;

String fieldNameAux = "id";
String classNameAux = "PedV";

try {
    c = Class.forName("beans."+classNameAux);
} catch (Exception e){}

Field f = c.getDeclaredField(fieldNameAux);
f.setAccessible(true);

f.set(**something**, ((Edit) objAux).getText();
```

As I need get the Class and the Field dynamically I can't use something like this (but it works):

```
Class<?> c = null;

String fieldNameAux = "id";
PedV pedV = new PedV();

c = pedV.getClass();

Field f = c.getDeclaredField(fieldNameAux);
f.setAccessible(true);

f.set(pedV, ((Edit) objAux).getText());
```

How could I substitute this `f.set(pedV, ((Edit) objAux).getText();` for something that works dynamically?

**OBS**: I'm getting `fieldNameAux` and `classNameAux` in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an *instance*. One way is via [`c.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--), which if this is a JavaBean should be all you need (it attempts to invoke the zero-args constructor for the class). Otherwise, you need to find an appropriate constructor via [`getDeclaredConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-)/[`getDeclaredConstructors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors--) or similar and then invoke them to get an instance.

Re your question in a comment:

> If i use `c.newInstance` it won't "kill"/clear my Field's values?

Your `Field` instance doesn't *have* values; the instance you get from `c.newInstance` does. `Field` is just a means of setting the data on the instance.

An example may help: Suppose we have:

```
public class Foo {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

Then we do this:

```
Class f = Class.forName("Foo");
Object inst = f.newInstance();
Field aField = f.getDeclaredField("a");
aField.setInt(inst, 42);
Field bField = f.getDeclaredField("b");
bField.setInt(inst, 67);
```

...now we have a `Foo` instance we're referring to via our `inst` variable, which has `a` equal to 42 and `b` equal to 67.

Comment: @TJCrowder Oh thanks, now I've got what you meant... it will help a lot